# Type null is not assignable to type IJobDetails (which is my interface)

Tags: c#, jquery, angular, typescript, interface

[image]

Below i have createed interface as ClientState1.
Now i want to create const descriptionJobDetails of type ClientState1 but it is throwing error as shown in figure

```
export interface ClientState1<State> {
      state: State;
      loading: boolean;
      error: any;
}

export interface IJobDetails {
    id: number;
    aboutTheCompany: string;
}

    const descriptionJobDetails: ClientState1<IJobDetails> = { state: null, loading: false, error: '' };
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using `strictNullChecks` or `strict` and this option prohibits you from assigning `null` to a type that does not explicitly accept `null`.

If you want to assign null to the field you can explicitly mark the field as accepting `null`:

```
interface ClientState1<State> {
    state: State | null;
    loading: boolean;
    error: any;
}
```

Or if you just want to put `null` in this field this one time because reasons, you can use the not null assertion operator (`!`):

```
const descriptionJobDetails: ClientState1<IJobDetails> = { state: null!, loading: false, error: '' };
```